# Firestore - How to make a field in a document update-able in Firestore Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm new to **Firebase Firestore database** and I'm struggling with a Security Rule for a document where it **only can be updated by the user who created it**. But, there is a **specific field** that I want any one one to update it. Of course it is only 1 field, so I don't want to have to create a **subcollection**.

Comment: see [rules.Path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path)

Comment: what do you mean? You mean from the client side or the console side?

Comment: Rules of the firebase firestore. Not the client side or the console.

Comment: To clarify the question; you have a document with fields. All of the fields except one can be only updated by the user that created the document. The one field can be updated by anyone. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is what I look for